# Floating in a header without a gap between the navigation list and the edge of the browser

Tags: css, floating

How do I float a navigation list in the header to the left without creating a gap to the left of the list?  Please tell me what I have to change or add in order to effect no gap?  On my screen, the gap is noticeable, about 1cm wide, and on the right navigation menu/list, there is no gap.  Please tell me how to make my left menu float like my right menu.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            header {text-align:center;}
            nav#right_menu > ul > li{display: block;float:right;position:relative; width:25px;}
            nav#left_menu > ul > li{display: block;float:left;position:relative; width:25px;padding: 0px;margin:0px; border:0px; text-align:left;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav id="left_menu">
                <ul id="left_menu">
                    <li>Hi1</li>
                    <li>Hi</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <nav id="right_menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>Hi1</li>
                    <li>Hi</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

markt answered this question, with ul {padding:0;}, and the code I added to fix this problem is: nav#left_menu > ul {padding:0;}
edit:  If I had this gap problem on both sides when floating, I would have used markt's exact code; however, I only had the issue with the left menu, hence I used my code, even though markt's code works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is padding on the ul

try adding:

```
ul { padding: 0; }
```

to your css

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer works! By the way, is 0 in pixels?

Comment: 0 is any unit you want it be! zero is zero whatever the units!